# Nat or Static Route in pfsense

Tags: nat, pfsense, route, static-routes

I installed PFsense on VMware with two interfaces.

```
1.WAN -> 192.168.1.110 ->Bridge   
      Getaway->192.168.1.1=>Modem IP

2.LAN -> 10.1.1.1 ->LAN Segment
```

how config Nat and Route to access to Internet (from Host Connect to 10.1.1.1 interface )And Modem(or 192.168.1.0/24 rang IP) ?

Answer (score 1):

Firewall -> NAT -> Outbound

There you can create a new rule for the WAN with source 10.1.1.0/24 and NAT address 'WAN address'.

This should automatically be done by pfsense if you assigned a WAN and LAN interface.

Also: Interfaces -> WAN

Make sure if you use static addresses that you have an IPv4 upstream Gateway set. If not, click on 'add a new one' and enter your gateway there.